# How do I use a LIKE or CONTAINS clause in SQL on the same row?

Tags: php, sql

In my project, you can list the ingredients you have and search for recipes that can be made with those ingredients. Here's my sample SQL query:
heres the database https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU8jo.png
i want to get the matching list.

```
SELECT recipes_Name 
FROM tblrecipes
INNER JOIN tblingredients
ON tblrecipes.recipes_ID = tblingredients.ingredients_ID
WHERE ingredients_name = variable1 AND variable2 AND variable3
```

Why is this query not working?

Comment: `ingredients_name = variable1 AND variable2 AND variable3` is read by sql like: `ingredients_name = variable1` and `variable2` and `variable3` is not blank

Comment: Are your recipes_ID and ingredients_ID the same type of ID? or should there be an intermediate table that includes the ingredients for each recipe (which would make your query easier)? The data structure you've provided doesn't look like it's set up to do what you need. Can you set up a Fiddle with an example of your data?

Comment: here's my database https://i.imgur.com/LgZ0WMD.png,, the have the same type of id .

Comment: What is `variable1`, `variable2`, etc? The `in` doesn't work?

Comment: "in" doesn't work because it functions like OR all variable must be true to get the recipe of the given ingredient

Comment: WHERE ingredients_name = variable1 AND ingredients_name = variable2 AND ingredients_name = variable3.. does not work if the column names are the same.

Comment: Can you add sample data as text, I have an idea but need to test it (or create a sqlfiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/). My second idea wouldnt work.

Comment: I'll undelete and update if I can get more data.

Comment: here http://textuploader.com/d9zqf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in` clause:

```
SELECT recipes_Name 
FROM tblrecipes
INNER JOIN tblingredients
ON tblrecipes.recipes_ID = tblingredients.ingredients_ID
WHERE ingredients_name in (variable1, variable2, variable3)
```

And my recommendation is to use [prepared statements with PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), by means of security.

**UPDATE:**

I've made query that will only fetch recipes with all ingredients specified (if even one ingredient is missing for the recipe it will not be included):

```
select
    rcp.*,
    ingr.selected_ingr_count
from
    tblrecipes rcp inner join(
        select
            ingredients_ID as recipe_id,
            count(*) as selected_ingr_count
        from
            tblingredients
        where
            ingredients_name in(
                'egg',
                'butter',
                'milk',
                'flour'
            )
        group by
            ingredients_ID
    ) as ingr on
    ingr.recipe_id = rcp.recipes_ID
    and ingr.selected_ingr_count =(
        select
            count(*)
        from
            tblingredients
        where
            tblingredients.ingredients_ID = rcp.recipes_ID
    )
```

This will result:

```
recipes_ID      recipes_Name        selected_ingr_count
        1       cake                3
        3       brownies            2
```

Comment: "in" doesn't work because it functions like OR all variable must be true to get the recipe of the given ingredient

Comment: Sorry for misundertanding. how u want it to work? for example if user chose ingredients 'egg' and 'butter', you wan to show all recipes that include any of the ingredients or only two of this (even missing any other ingredients).?

Comment: thank you so much!! I've been struggling for days . :D